# Why am I getting error: "Cannot access disposed object" in .net core 2 with EF and AutoFac?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, autofac

First the error:

> ```
> Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and
> ```
>
> then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your
>   application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the
>   context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are
>   using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection
>   container take care of disposing context instances.
>       Object name: 'MemberContext'.

I have 3 projects, Domain, API and WebSPA app.

Domain has 2 modules, DomainModule and MediatorModule

```
 public class DomainModule : Autofac.Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MemberContext).Assembly)
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope(); // via assembly scan

            builder.RegisterType<MemberContext>().AsSelf()
                    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();          // or individually
        }
    }

 public class MediatorModule : Autofac.Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            // enables contravariant Resolve() for interfaces with single contravariant ("in") arg
            builder
                .RegisterSource(new ContravariantRegistrationSource());

            // mediator itself
            builder
                .RegisterType<Mediator>()
                .As<IMediator>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            // request handlers
            builder
                .Register<SingleInstanceFactory>(ctx =>
                {
                    var c = ctx.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
                    return t =>
                    {
                        object o;
                        return c.TryResolve(t, out o) ? o : null;
                    };
                })
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            // notification handlers
            builder
                .Register<MultiInstanceFactory>(ctx =>
                {
                    var c = ctx.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
                    return t => (IEnumerable<object>) c.Resolve(typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(t));
                })
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        }
    }
```

In API project I have also 2 modules, ApplicationModule and again MediatorModule same as the one above.

```
 public class ApplicationModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Startup).Assembly)
                        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                        .InstancePerLifetimeScope(); // via assembly scan

            builder.RegisterType<MemberContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();          // or individually
        }
    }
```

No, when I debug I can see that member context gets newed up on each request, yet on second request, it throws above error. To make sure I am not going crazy, I modified constructor of dbcontext to create an id for context so i can verify they are different. What am I doing wrong?

```
 public MemberContext(DbContextOptions<MemberContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            MemberContextId = Guid.NewGuid();

            Console.WriteLine("member context created: " + MemberContextId);

        }
```

Here is the startup in API

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                //    .AllowCredentials()
            );
        });

        services.AddMvc()
                .AddControllersAsServices();//Injecting Controllers themselves thru DI
                        //For further info see: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#controllers-as-services

        AddSwaggerGen(services);

        //var connection = Configuration["ConnectionString"];

        //services.AddDbContext<MemberContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection),ServiceLifetime.Scoped);


        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<MemberContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString"]
                        //,sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                        //{
                        //    sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name);
                        //    sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 10, maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), errorNumbersToAdd: null);
                        //}
                        );
                },
                ServiceLifetime.Scoped  //Showing explicitly that the DbContext is shared across the HTTP request scope (graph of objects started in the HTTP request)
            );


        var container = new ContainerBuilder();
        container.Populate(services);

        container.RegisterAssemblyModules(typeof(VIN.Members.Domain.Entities.Member).Assembly,
                                          typeof(Startup).Assembly);


        return new AutofacServiceProvider(container.Build());
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        //NOTE: must be before UseMVC !!!
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseMvc();

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });
    }

    private void AddSwaggerGen(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info
            {
                Title = "VIN Members HTTP API",
                Version = "v1",
                Description = "Members Service HTTP API",
                TermsOfService = "Terms Of Service"
            });
        });
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

What I am trying to do is delete a record. On client side code looks like this

```
 onDelete(item: IMember) {
        //TODO: replace this with dialog service component
        if (window.confirm('Are sure you want to delete this member?')) {
            //put your delete method logic here
            this.service.deleteMember(item).subscribe(x => {

                this.getMembers();
            });
        }
    }
```

this delete request gets mapped to a controller that passes it to mediator

Controller

```
  // DELETE api/members/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(Guid id)
        {
            var command = new DeleteMember.Command(id);

            _mediator.Send(command).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

and finally handler

```
public class DeleteMember
{
    public class Command : IRequest
    {
        public Command(Guid memberId)
        {
            Guard.NotNull(memberId, nameof(memberId));

            MemberId = memberId;
        }

        public Guid MemberId { get; }

    }

    public class Handler : AsyncRequestHandler<Command>
    {
        private MemberContext _context;

        public Handler(MemberContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            Console.WriteLine("Delete member context: " + context.MemberContextId);
        }

        protected override async Task HandleCore(Command cmd)
        {
            try
            {
                var member = await _context.FindAsync<Member>(cmd.MemberId);//.ConfigureAwait(false);

               // if (member != null)
               //// {
                    _context.Remove(member);

                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
               // }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there is no code that disposes that context. Scratching my head.

See this commented out check for member if null. That was throwing error as well, I commented it out just to see what will happen, and now it throws as SaveChangesAsync.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As request completes, context gets disposed. Since command handler uses SaveChangesAsync(), context is disposed before save completes. Culprit is controller method :). It should be async as well.

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task Delete(Guid id)
{
    var command = new DeleteMember.Command(id);

   await _mediator.Send(command).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `DbContext` is scoped, meaning that Dependency Injection will return the same `DbContext` object every time one is asked for within the same HTTP request (in the case of ASP.NET).

That means that you should not be calling `Dispose` on your `DbContext` (otherwise that same object can't be used a second time). That seems to be what is happening to you, intentionally or not.

That does mean you should not be using `using` with it. Are you using `using` anywhere in your code against your `DbContext`?

I don't think you showed the line where the Exception is being thrown.

*Update:*
Try overriding `Dispose` in your `MemberContext` class. Something like this:

```
public override void Dispose() {
    base.Dispose();
}
```

But just set a breakpoint there. When it breaks (if it does) check the stack trace and see what called it.

Comment: I'm stumped. Maybe it's Autofac? I have no experience with Autofac. I updated my answer with a suggestion to hunt it down.

Comment: Hmm, there is not overridable Dispose method, but I implemented IDisposable  on my dbContext and nothing calls it.

Comment: That's odd. `DbContext` implements `IDisposible`, so it should be there.... oh! Looks like what I told you is wrong. I updated the code for the `Dispose` method. Sorry. I actually tested it this time :)

Comment: This is crazy . First request, new context, passed in as dependency, runs query, gets disposed. Next request, again new context gets instantiated and passed as dependency, but when accessed it says it is disposed, even though it has not been disposed yet. Arrrggghhhhh

Comment: I did a little reading about Autofac. My best guess is that you'll have to tweak your `RegisterType` line.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by having async void instead of async Task within WebAPI in my experience.