# EF Core: Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I use DataContext.

`Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options
            .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
            .UseSqlServer(connString));
```

constructor of my class:

```
    private readonly DataContext _dbContext;
    public TagService(DataContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
```

method:

```
    public async Task UpdateTagAsync(TagUpdateDto tagDto)
    {
        var tag = _dbContext.Tags.Where(p => p.Id == tagDto.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        tag = _mapper.Map<TagUpdateDto, Tag>(tagDto, tag);
        tag.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        _dbContext.Tags.Update(tag);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

then I call this method by the following way:

```
        TagDisplayDto tagDto = _service.GetTag(id);

        TagUpdateAPI tagForUpdate = _mapper.Map<TagUpdateAPI>(tagDto);
        jsonPatchDocument.ApplyTo(tagForUpdate);

        TagUpdateDto tagUpdateDto = _mapper.Map<TagUpdateDto>(tagForUpdate);
        _service.UpdateTagAsync(tagUpdateDto);
```

where GetTag is:

```
    public TagDisplayDto GetTag(int id)
    {
        var tag = _dbContext.Tags.Where(p => p.Id == id).ProjectTo<TagDisplayDto>(_mapperConfig).FirstOrDefault();
        if (tag == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException();

        return tag;
    }
```

on the calling `SaveChangesAsync` it throws an exception:

> "Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.\r\nObject name: 'DataContext'."

but changes really saved. Why so?

Comment: Is this of any use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48747982/why-am-i-getting-error-cannot-access-disposed-object-in-net-core-2-with-ef-a?rq=1

Comment: Did you forget to `await` the `_service.UpdateTagAsync(tagUpdateDto);` call?

Comment: @mjwills, yes, just lost await :) Thank you!